# Sum two Float fields from two models, on the same form - Odoo v8

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8

Suppose I have:

```
class Model1(models.Model):

    name = fields.Char(string="Name")
    one_1 = fields.One2many('Model2', 'field_many', string="")
    one_2 = fields.One2many('Model3', 'field_many2', string="")
    one_3 = fields.One2many('Model4', 'field_many3', string="")
```

These are the models called from `One2many` fields:

```
class Model2(models.Model):
    field_many = fields.Many2one('Model1', string="")
    field_float1 = fields.Float()

class Model3(models.Model):
    field_many2 = fields.Many2one('Model1', string="")
    field_float2 = fields.Float()

class Model4(models.Model):
    field_many3 = fields.Many2one('Model1', string="")
    field_float3 = fields.Float()
```

I need to sum `field_float1` and `field_float2` and show the result on `field_float3`, but the problem is, or what gets me confused for what matters, is the fact that this sum isn't just a sum in the same model.

I could do:

```
@api.onchange('field_float1', 'field_float2')
def _compute_amount_move_sales_current(self):
    if self.field_float1 or self.field_float2:
        self.field_float3 = self.field_float1 + self.field_float2
```

But these are fields from two models, which result should be reflected on third model field, also, these models are represented on `Model1` form, through 3 `One2many` tree view, or lines as they are often called into Odoo.

So, it's just about to read the first two fields, but it must be on the form `Model1` which will create the new record. Not the db table.

**EDIT**

This is a more precise explanation, a user creates a new record with these lines or `One2many` fields, in all cases the first two must be filled, so I think that can be achieved with `required=True` flag on the fields.
However, I've tried this way:

```
class Model1(models.Model):

    name = fields.Char(string="Name")
    one_1 = fields.One2many('Model2', 'field_many', string="")
    one_2 = fields.One2many('Model3', 'field_many2', string="")
    one_3 = fields.One2many('Model4', 'field_many3', string="", onchange="compute_sum")
    @api.onchange('one_1', 'one_2')
    def compute_sum(self):
        if self.one_1.field_float1 or self.one_2.field_float2:
        self.one_3.field_float3 = self.one_1.field_float1 + self.one_2.field_float2
```

But it doesn't work, whenever I fill one of the required field_float it says:

```
    ValueError

Expected singleton: Model4()
```

For further explanation, the Models look like this:

```
class Model2(models.Model):
    field_many = fields.Many2one('Model1', string="")
    field_float1 = fields.Float()
    field_float_ = fields.Float()
    field_integer = fields.Integer()
    field_char = fields.Char()

class Model3(models.Model):
    field_many2 = fields.Many2one('Model1', string="")
    field_float2 = fields.Float()
    integer = fields.Integer()

class Model4(models.Model):
    field_many3 = fields.Many2one('Model1', string="")
    field_float3 = fields.Float()
    chars = fields.Char()
    bool = fields.Boolean()
```

I mean, there are several fields on each of these models, which are called from `Model1` with `One2many` fields, just those floats need the operation, not every one of them.

And the user will be filling these fields in order, with a `state` like form, with `statusbar` etc, in order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution work if you want to sum

```
field1 of record1 In first one2many field with field2 of record1 In second one2many field to put the the result in field3 of the first record.
```

It's a start to understand what you need exactly. 
In your model1 makr third one2many field a compute field

```
                   @api.depends ('one_1', 'one_2','one_1.field1', 'one_2.field2')
                    def compute_sum(self):
                          # Then loop throw your records and compute sum
```

I would write more cde for you but i'm using my phone i may edit my answer later hope at least you get the idea.

If you use onchange it may work too when user change the value of the float field but remove one_1.field1 if you use it.

Just remember you need to define the method in yout model1 becausr it's there where you have full access

Comment: Thank You very much, gotta try and do some tests

Comment: Hi, but now all the line is readonly, I mean, I've used just one field in the example because it was an example, it is to some extent like that, but there are also some other fields on this One2many which shouldn't be computed, that's the problem I think

Comment: Imagine my example, with 2 other fields on their own which shouldn't be computed, Idk if I should edit my question for that, your solution I think, works out only if I have literally one field on ´one_3´

Comment: Yes you are right. But i didn't get your logic is user going to create a record in the firsr o2m then a record in second o2m and when he create a record in third o2m then you compute the value. If it's like that than don't use compute use onchange event, check length of your field to know how to compute your values because use can create a recors in first o2m and third and leave the second one empty. Explain how user use your view to create a record